# jQuery categorized autocomplete gives ui.item is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I want to have a categorized autocomplete search in my Rails 3.2 app, written in jQuery 1.9.1. I have the following code:

```
jQuery.widget( "custom.catcomplete", jQuery.ui.autocomplete, {
        _renderItemData: function( ul, item ) {
            return jQuery( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
        },

        _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
            var that = this,
            currentCategory = "";
            jQuery.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                    if (item.category != undefined) {
                        ul.append( "<li>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                        currentCategory = item.category;
          }
                }
                that._renderItemData( ul, item );
            });
        },


    });



  jQuery('.search-query').catcomplete({
    appendTo: '#search_query_wrapper',
    source: '/some_url',
        select: function( event, ul ) {
            console.log(ul);
            jQuery.get(ul.item.value);
    }
    });
```

It actually renders its items correctly, but when I click on any of them, I get the following error in Firebug:

```
TypeError: ul.item is undefined 

jQuery.get(ul.item.value)
```

What's wrong? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `jQuery.get()`? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: the `ui.item.value` should have an url. By selecting the item, I should be doing a get request to that url. The purpose of it is to fill some form fields without reloading the page

Comment: Use `console.log(ui.item)` and  tell me what members are in the object

Comment: `console.log(ui.item)` gives me `undefined`

Comment: What does the JSON data look like from your `source`?

Comment: This is and example. Notice the url in the value key and the html in the label key, which is displayed correctly in the app:

`[{"value":"/students/27853/fill_fields?guardian_id=26277","label":"<img alt=\"Student\" height=\"20\" src=\"/assets/misc/student.png\" width=\"20\" />  DIANA CAROLINA ZAMBRANO RUEDA"},{"value":"/students/27854/fill_fields?guardian_id=26277","label":"<img alt=\"Student\" height=\"20\" src=\"/assets/misc/student.png\" width=\"20\" />  PAOLA ANDREINA BERMAN RUDA"}]`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yTMwu/53/ I am not getting undefined.

Comment: it worked perfectly, so I began messing around and found out that it's working with jQuery UI 1.9.2, but not with jQuery UI 1.10.0, which was the version I had in my app. I've updated the code to your fiddle to show it fails when using that version of jQuery UI. If you want, please answer the question so I can check it and get you some well deserved points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided works! Just use `jQuery UI 1.9.2` script.

DEMO: 
http://jsfiddle.net/yTMwu/53/

Let me know if you need anything else!